# Get the innermost array in PHP

Tags: php

Below shown is my posted data from a form. Since i used a multiform approach,i got the posted data as an array. I want to save each value in to the database,ie 1,2,3.etc since it is the attribute "since_value" value.How would i get only the values as array from this?

```
Array ( 

   [0] => Array ( [some_value] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) 
   [1] => Array ( [some_value] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) )
   [2] => Array ( [some_value] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) ) 
   [3] => Array ( [some_value] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) ) 
   [4] => Array ( [some_value] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) ) 
   [5] => Array ( [some_value] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) ) 
   [6] => Array ( [some_value] => Array ( [0] => 7 ) )

 )
```

I want to make it like

```
 Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 )
```

How will i do it?

I tried like

```
  $x=implode('',$array);
```

But it gives me an Array to string conversion error.

Comment: First, show us what have you tried?

Comment: with the help of loop

Comment: I tried implode and array_map function. But it gives me an array to string conversion error

Comment: @DencyGB: Using `array_map()`, it would be something like: `$res = array_map(function($item) { return $item['some_value'][0]; }, $arr);`

Comment: Please review my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php

$arr=Array (

    0 => Array ( 'some_value' => Array ( 0 => 1 ) ),
    1 => Array ( 'some_value' => Array ( 0 => 2 ) ),
    2 => Array ( 'some_value' => Array ( 0 => 3 ) ),
    3 => Array ( 'some_value' => Array ( 0 => 4 ) ),
    4 => Array ( 'some_value' => Array ( 0 => 5 ) ),
    5 => Array ( 'some_value' => Array ( 0 => 6 ) ),
    6 => Array ( 'some_value' => Array ( 0 => 7 ) )

);
    $new_arr= array();
    foreach($arr as $arr1)
    {
        foreach($arr1['some_value'] as $v){
        $new_arr[]=$v;
        }
    }

    print_r($new_arr);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://eval.in/105857)</kbd>

### EDITED

Using Single foreach

```
$new_arr= array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$arr1)
{
    $new_arr[]=$arr1['some_value'][0];
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: You don't need a second `foreach` - `$new_arr[] = $arr1['some_value'][0]` would be fine. See: https://eval.in/105859

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array('some_value' => array(1) ),
    array('some_value' => array(2) ),
    array('some_value' => array(3) ),
    array('some_value' => array(4) ),
    array('some_value' => array(5) ),
    array('some_value' => array(6) ),
    array('some_value' => array(7) ),
);

$output = array();
foreach($data as $k => $v)
{
    $output[$k] = $v['some_value'][0];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function array_flatten($array) {

   $return = array();
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
       if (is_array($value)){ $return = array_merge($return, array_flatten($value));}
       else {$return[$key] = $value;}
   }
   return $return;

}

$array  = array ( 
           array ( "some_value" => array ( 1 ) ), 
           array ( "some_value" => array ( 2 ) ),
           array ( "some_value" => array ( 3 ) ),
           array ( "some_value" => array ( 4 ) ), 
           array ( "some_value" => array ( 5 ) ),
           array ( "some_value" => array ( 6 ) ),
           array ( "some_value" => array ( 7 ) )
        );
$result = array_flatten($array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

Comment: Please explain -1 so that I can change / improve / delete the answer

Comment: This works just fine, not sure why it was down-voted. +1.

Comment: It's not my downvote, but I think a recursive function is overkill for something simple as this.

Comment: @AmalMurali : Yes I know but structure of tha array can change so I guess this is the best method

Comment: @AmalMurali : I mean there can be more "inner arrays"

Comment: +1 for forseeing the "more inner arrays" ! :-)